# if username in dataframe 1 is equal to username in dateframe 2 then place the nextcolumn in dataframe 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

dataframe 1 is

```
View Name       member             user id
Admin_Case_View Catherine Kear     ckear
Admin_IT        Atul Dhiwar        adhiwar-sa
Admin_IT        Costin Bulisache   cbulisac
Admin_IT        Deepa Gopal        SA
Admin_IT        Geoff Semonian     SA
Admin_IT        Glenn Castan       SA
Admin_IT        Nikhil Manekar     nmanekar
Admin_Questions Chaitanya Kondury  kkondury
Admin_Questions Geetha Maddala     gmaddala
Admin_Questions Kelly Kim          jungeunk
Admin_Questions Megan Yeh          megany
```

dataframe 2 is

```
Case Owner Alias    Owner Region
cbulisac            Other
aandiapp            India
gmaddala            North America
abarak              Europe
abell               Europe
nmanekar            India
abhghos             India
kkondury            India
abhishuk            India
acai                China
megany              North America
adasari             India
adhiwar-sa          North America
```

here if username in dataframe 1 is equal to username in dataframe 2 then place the region in dataframe 1.

output should be :-

```
    View Name       member           user id          region
    Admin_Case_View Catherine Kear    ckear         
    Admin_IT        Atul Dhiwar       adhiwar-sa      North America 
    Admin_IT        Costin Bulisache  cbulisac        Other
    Admin_IT        Deepa Gopal       SA
    Admin_IT        Geoff Semonian    SA
    Admin_IT        Glenn Castan      SA
    Admin_IT        Nikhil Manekar    nmanekar       India
    Admin_Questions Chaitanya Kondury kkondury       india
    Admin_Questions Geetha Maddala    gmaddala       North America 
    Admin_Questions Kelly Kim         jungeunk       Europe 
    Admin_Questions Megan Yeh         adhiwar-sa     North America
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this you just need merge,

```
df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on=['user id'],right_on=['Case Owner Alias'],how='left').rename(columns={'Owner Region':'region'}).drop('Case Owner Alias',1).fillna('')
```

O/P:

```
          View Name             member     user id         region
0   Admin_Case_View     Catherine Kear       ckear            
1          Admin_IT        Atul Dhiwar  adhiwar-sa  North America
2          Admin_IT   Costin Bulisache    cbulisac          Other
3          Admin_IT        Deepa Gopal          SA            
4          Admin_IT     Geoff Semonian          SA            
5          Admin_IT       Glenn Castan          SA            
6          Admin_IT     Nikhil Manekar    nmanekar          India
7   Admin_Questions  Chaitanya Kondury    kkondury          India
8   Admin_Questions     Geetha Maddala    gmaddala  North America
9   Admin_Questions          Kelly Kim    jungeunk            
10  Admin_Questions          Megan Yeh      megany  North America
```

Note: Map is not advisable when you have a large Dataframe.